# subquery returns more than 1 row, input data pass with minimal value

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
Insert into graduated (id_graduated , id_results)
VALUES ('L1',(SELECT id_results FROM results WHERE score >= 40));
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO graduated (id_graduated, id_results)
SELECT 'L1', id_results FROM results WHERE score >= 40
```